$\operatorname{Hess}r$ is scalar matrix $\implies$ $M$ is isometric to the space form
I'm trying to prove the rigidity part of a theorem in my paper, which requires the use of the classical Hessian comparison theorem's rigidity part:
$$\DeclareMathOperator\sn{sn}\operatorname{Hess}r=\frac{\sn_k'}{\sn_k}{\rm d}s_{n-1}^2 \implies g={\rm d}r^2+\sn_k^2{\rm d}s_{n-1}^2,$$
where $r$ is the distance function to a point $p\in M$ and
$$\sn_k(t)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin\sqrt kt}{\sqrt k} & k>0,\\
t& k=0,\\
\dfrac{\sinh\sqrt{|k|}t}{\sqrt{|k|}} & k<0.
\end{cases}$$
I have searched many textbooks that introduce Riemannian geometry, but these textbooks all say that this is an obvious thing and explain it roughly, which makes me very confused because I have tried some methods myself, but they are too complex for me to extend the main theorem in my paper to the case of Kaehler. So is there any simple way to explain this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated! ${}$

This question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com. You should move it to there.

After a period of calculation and consulting with my advisor, I have come up with this method.
Let $J=J(t)$ be a Jacobi field along $\gamma$ such that $J~\bot~\dot{\gamma}={\rm grad~} r$ and $J(0)=0$, then by pushforward formula of Lie brackets:
$$F_*[X_1,X_2]=[F_*X_1,F_*X_2],$$
we have $[J,{\rm grad~} r]=0$. Torsion-freeness implies
$$J'=\nabla_{{\rm grad~} r}J=\nabla_J{\rm grad~} r.$$
Let $\{e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}\}$ be an orthonormal basis perpendicular to ${\rm grad~} r$, then for each $j=1,\cdots,n-1$, we have
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
   \langle J',e_j\rangle & =\langle\nabla_J{\rm grad~} r,e_j\rangle \\
   & ={\rm Hess~}r(J,e_j) \\
   & ={\rm Hess~}r\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\langle J,e_i\rangle e_i,e_j\right) \\
   & =\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\langle J,e_i\rangle{\rm Hess~}r(e_i,e_j) \\
   & =\langle J,e_j\rangle{\rm Hess~}r(e_j,e_j) \\
   & =\left\langle \frac{{\rm sn}_k'(t)}{{\rm sn}_k(t)}J,e_j\right\rangle.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
That is
$$J'(t)=\frac{{\rm sn}_k'(t)}{{\rm sn}_k(t)}J(t).$$
Let $J_i(t)$ be Jacobi fields that satisfy the above condition, and satisfy
$$J_i(0)=0, \quad J_i'(0)=e_i(0), \quad i=1,\cdots,n-1,$$
then it is not difficult to see that
$$J_i(t)={\rm sn}_k(t)e_i(t).$$
Therefore $M$ is isometric to $n$-dimensional simply connected space form with constant sectional curvature $k$.
